# How to optimize the T-SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a T-SQL Query, I am developing the e-commerce website, in that I am using 4 major tables:

1. ProductCategory
2. Product
3. OrderLineItem
4. Order

I have a one page in my admin section for manage the orders, Now I want to filter by `ProductCategory` i.e. which `Order` contains the `Product` (my `productId` is in `OrderLineItem` table) which is related to the selected `ProductCategory`, I am doing this via below query:

```
SELECT  
    O.OrderID,O.[OrderDate],O.[StatusID]                          
FROM [Order] O                              
INNER JOIN [Dyve_User] U ON U.[UserID] = O.[UserID]                               
INNER JOIN (SELECT OD.OrderID 
            FROM OrderLineItem OD
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [Product] P ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProductCategory] PC ON PC.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
            WHERE 
               (P.CategoryID = COALESCE(@CategoryID, P.CategoryID)                              
                OR P.CategoryID IN (SELECT CategoryID 
                                    FROM ProductCategory                              
                                    WHERE ParentID = COALESCE(@CategoryID, ParentID)
                                   )
               )                              
           ) AS T  ON O.OrderID = T.OrderID
```

My this query return the correct result but the query times out every time, can any one tell me how to optimize this query so this will not time out?

following is the tables schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
[OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
[OrderTax] [money] NULL,
[OrderTotal] [money] NULL,
[ShippingCharge] [money] NULL,
[TrackingNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TransactionStatusID] [int] NULL,
[UserID] [int] NULL,
[PromotionCode] [varchar](50) NULL
[ExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
[PaymentType] [tinyint] NULL
  CONSTRAINT [Order_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
[OrderID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Product Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
[ProductID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CategoryID] [int] NULL,
[ProductName] [nvarchar](600) NULL,
[ManufacturerID] [int] NULL,
[UnitPrice] [money] NULL,
[RetailPrice] [money] NULL,
[IsOnSale] [bit] NOT NULL,
[ExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
[IsElectrical] [bit] NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NULL,
[ProductType] [int] NULL,
[AllowBackOrder] [bit] NULL
   CONSTRAINT [Product_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
[ProductID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

ProductCategory Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductCategory](
[CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ParentID] [int] NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NULL
    CONSTRAINT [ProductCategory_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
[CategoryID] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

OrderLineItem Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderLineItem](
[OrderDetailID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL
[TotalPrice] [money] NULL,
[Quantity] [int] NULL,
[Discount] [money] NULL,
[UnitPrice] [money] NULL,
[UserID] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [OrderLineItem_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
      (
[OrderDetailID] ASC
   )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Why you doing LEFT JOIN here if you want to see only products from specific category?
 FROM OrderLineItem OD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProductCategory] PC ON PC.CategoryID = P.CategoryID             WHERE                 (P.CategoryID = COALESCE(@CategoryID, P.CategoryID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested so I'm not sure if it still does what you intended with your query.

It will fetch the `Order`s that has an `OrderLineItem` with a `Product` with a `CategoryID` that is equal to `@CategoryID` or a child category to `@CategoryID`.

```
SELECT O.OrderID,
       O.[OrderDate],
       O.[StatusID]
FROM   [Order] AS O
WHERE  O.OrderID IN (SELECT OD.OrderID
                     FROM   OrderLineItem AS OD
                            INNER JOIN Product AS P
                              ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT PC.CategoryID
                                        FROM   ProductCategory
                                        WHERE  ParentID = @CategoryID
                                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT @CategoryID) AS C
                              ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID)
```

With regards to performance you just have to test it to find out.

Indexes is a good thing and you should make sure that you have indexes on your foreign key columns.

Comment: I have tried this way but getting same Time Out Error, please suggest me any other way

Comment: @Vijjendra - It might be helpful if you could update your question with the table structures (DDL) including any indexes, how many rows each table contain and how many rows you expect to be returned with this query. Have you tried to run the query in SSMS?

Comment: my order table contains arround 15k rows, products table arround 1.5k category table arround 50 and OrderLineItem contains arround 22k rows, I want to return 25 or 50 records.

Comment: @Vijjendra - That is not much. I have tested this query with that amount of data on a laptop with 2GB memory and  Intel Duo 1,20 GHz. It took 300 ms. Your problem with the timeout is something else. Have you tried to run the query in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to start with:

1. Define indexes on the join and where columns.
2. Join from the smaller tables to the bigger ones.

I suggest reading up on performance and how to find causes - here is a good article on the subject: [part 1](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/) and [part 2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-2/).

Comment: what do you mean Join from the smaller tables to the bigger ones??

Comment: @Vijjendra - Start with the tables that have less data and join into bigger tables.

Answer (score 0):

First try to make longer timeout to see it work. Than take a loot at your execution plan. Move tables with less elements to the left of the join.

Comment: How to Move tables with less elements to the left of the join?

Comment: This is what @Oded commented "Start with the tables that have less data and join into bigger tables"